# TTTAttributedLabel clickable link does not work in Swift 3

Tags: uilabel, swift3, tttattributedlabel

I just upgraded to Swift 3. I created a TTTAttributedLabel with a clickable URL, unfortunately the delegate function does not work anymore. Anyone has similar problems?

```
    func attributedLabel(_ label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWith url: URL!) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   extension YourViewController: TTTAttributedLabelDelegate {   
        func attributedLabel(_ label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWith url: URL!) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to connect the delegate?

label.delegate = self

It is working for me

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks.